# How to compare user input to a file using a user.&pass. system while in a temporary loop for 3 times in C

Tags: c, loops, file-io

I have been wrecking my brain over this, as the program runs it needs to create a .txt file then be able to read usernames and passwords from it. Then compare what the user inputs to what's written in the .txt file. As well the program can only ask the user three times for the username and password before ending.

Here is the code I've been trying to tweak, but I keep breaking it and then trying to fix it and then it get's worse and worse.

My problem is that I cannot get the code to recognize what the user has inputted to be the same string as what's in the .txt file, or vice versa and then output if the user is has entered a correct or false usr/pass combo.

```
#define LSIZ 128
#define RSIZ 10

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE * fpw;
FILE * fpr;

double identfilecreate(char[LSIZ]);
int passverify(int);

int main() {
    
    char userandpin[LSIZ];
    int i = 0;
  
    identfilecreate(userandpin); //Calling the file creation
    
    
    fpr = fopen("ident.txt", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //Trying to make it three attempts for the loop
        
        passverify(i);

        //Notifying the user of how many tries are left
        printf("You have %d more tries\n", 2-i);
    }
    if ((i = 2)){ //Once three tries are over, the program ends
        printf("The program will now end\n");
        return 0;
    }
        
        
    fclose(fpr);
    
    return 0;
}


double identfilecreate(){
    char line[RSIZ][LSIZ];
    int i = 0;
    int tot = 0;
    
    fpw = fopen("ident.txt", "w");
    //Opens and overwrites any previous ident.txt file with what is needed
    fprintf(fpw, "Mark\t12345\nHannah\t23456\nJohn\t34567\nSammy\t45678\nDom\t56789\nOlivia\t67890\n");
    //I need these users to be matched with these passwords
    //This was the only way I could get it to format correctly into the .txt file
    fclose(fpw);

    fpr = fopen("ident.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fpr)) //reads the .txt file, assigns strings to an array
       {
           line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
           i++;
       }
    tot = i;
    fclose(fpr);
    return 0;
}


int passverify(){
    char user[LSIZ], pin[LSIZ], userandpin[LSIZ], line[RSIZ][LSIZ];;
    int i = 0;
    
    printf("Please enter your username: ");
    scanf("%s", user);
    printf("Please enter your pin:  ");
    scanf("%s", pin);
    
    //Combining the user input into one string so I can compare it later
    strcpy(userandpin, user);
    strcat(userandpin, "\t");
    strcat(userandpin, pin);
    
    while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fpr))
       {
           line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
           i++;
       }

  //This is where I am stuck, I can't seem to make any code work, while in a 3 times loop
    if ((strcmp(userandpin, line[i])) == 0)
        printf("You can entered the correct username and password.\n");
    else
        printf("You have entered the wrong username and password.\n");
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it works the first time, we have a solution to make it work three times.

```
fpr = fopen("ident.txt", "r");
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //Trying to make it three attempts for the loop
    fseek(fpr, 0, SEEK_SET);  
    /* FIXME check return code! */
    passverify(i);

    //Notifying the user of how many tries are left
    printf("You have %d more tries\n", 2-i);
}
```

Where `fseek()` is the critical function. We want to read the file every time we go around the loop.

But your passverify function doesn't return whether or not it matched so you need to fix that too. In addition, we need to check inside the loop not outside it.

```
while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fpr))
   {
       line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
       // We need to check inside the loop not outside it!
       // think about it; we need to check every user in the file
       if ((strcmp(userandpin, line[i])) == 0)
       {
          printf("You can entered the correct username and password.\n");
          return 1;
       }
   }
   // If we got here nothing matched
   printf("You have entered the wrong username and password.\n");
   return 0;
```